# how to find the limit of this sequence $u_n= \frac{(-1)^n}{(-1)^{n-1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

hey guys can you tell the limit value of this sequence as n ----->+inf

\begin{align}
                             \\
    Un&= \frac{(-1)^n}{(-1)^{n-1}}
  \end{align}
**i get -1**   ; but i don't if it is true or not?
thx in advance

Answer (score 3):

Since $$u_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{(-1)^{n-1}} = (-1)^{n-(n-1)} = (-1)^{1} = {-1}$$

it easily follows that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}-1 = -1$$

So you were correct.

Comment: thanks i am really dumb hhhhh

Comment: If an answer helped you, you can give it an upvote and accept it. Then, others will know that your question has been solved.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{(-1)^n}{(-1)^{n-1}}=(-1)^{n-(n-1)}=(-1)^1=-1$, meaning that the sequence has a constant value.
 Intuitively speaking, when $(-1)^n$ is odd, then $(-1)^{n-1}$ is even or vice versa and for every $n$, $U_n$ is either $\frac{-1}{1}$ or $\frac{1}{-1}$, which both equal $-1$.

Edit: Since every number in the sequence is equal to a constant, namely $-1$, the limit of the series will equal that constant as well. So $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}u_n=-1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(-1)^{n-1}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(-1)^{n}(-1)^{-1}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{(-1)^{-1}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}-1 = -1$$

So, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

This sequence do not depend on $n$ it is constant all terms are equal to $-1$